# Trim down the node_modules when creating Lambda Layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-lambda-layers

When creating a JavaScript Lambda Layer, the AWS documents say that we should zip the entire node_modules folder and push into the Layer. But, there is a lot of redundant code in the node_modules folder. All that is not required when running the Lambda Function.
Is there a generic way to trim down the node_modules folder to increase the make the efficiency of the Lambda Function using that layer?

Comment: Why do you have redundant code in the node_modules folder? Are you talking about dev/test dependencies? 

aws-sdk is always included in AWS lambda, so that dependency doesn't have to be included. But besides that, everything you use in the function needs to be bundled.

Comment: Most of the packages in the node_modules have an src, dist, min, a .md fille, license files.. Each of those occupies space. In fact, the real code would around 30% of the node_modules folder. All of this adds  to the memory usage in the Lambda. Better to cut it off.

Comment: unreferenced files like src files (when there is a dist) and readmes etc won't take up memory usage in the lambda, only storage.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit--when you say "generic way," the generic way is to use a filter when creating the layer zip.  Filter out the stuff you don't want.  Are you looking for a generic way to filter what gets installed by npm?  Or to filter what gets included in the zip?  In short, I think you'll only get generic answers to your request for a "generic way," so if you can make your question more specific you are likely to get specific answers that are more likely to help.

Comment: @Shawn I can manually enter each folder in the node_modules, to identify and delete all that is not required. Generic way.. I mean some command that I run, that identifies and clears all the clutter in the node_modules folder